# Blocking Methods Like fcntl() and accept(), Which One of The Requesters Will Get It?

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I'm reading php-cgi's source code and sees that the forked child processes are using fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) to wait for a lock of the socket fd and then do accept().

```
FCGI_LOCK(req->listen_socket);
req->fd = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &len);
FCGI_UNLOCK(req->listen_socket);
```

So my questions are:

1. When several processes/threads are trying to lock a file with fcntl(), which one will get it?
2. If several processes are all doing accept() from the same socket fd (they can, right?), which one will get it?
3. Again, in nginx source code, I see the forked process are setting epoll events on the same socket fd, when an event comes, which one will get it?

random? round-robin? fifo? lru? ...

Actually I'm just trying to figure out the load balancing strategy of these models.

Answer (score 0):

As I read on UNIX Network Programming Volume 1, it's the kernel that helps load-balancing the events, evenly. But how does the kernel do it is beyond me, hope someone could clarify it and cite some codes. Also I'm going to read the source code in the future, maybe I can find the answer by myself.